# Abstract classes in Java

Tags: java, class, graph, nodes, abstract

So, I have an object-oriented assignment to do. Small part of it is to make a graph, made out of nodes, which can be either a type category or type product.

The category has only a name ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) as parameters.

The product hast a name ([a-zA-Z0-9]+) and an id (>=0).

At the beginning a made just a node, with two objects category in product, which where both null, and depending on the input I created an instance of one of the two things, and everything was fine.

I really put a thought in it and after I checked the lectures I found about the thing abstract classes :D . No my idea is to make Node abstract and Product and Category extending Node,since:

Category has setter and getter for Name and toString
Product has setter and getter for Name AND ID (of course) and toString.

Setter,getter and toString for Name are identical.
There's a differnce in the constructor for Product, because it sets also the ID.

So,
Is it going to work that way, is it better?
Can I create a Node and then after the input say -> this node is from type category

Comment: Your question is really `abstract` at the moment. Consider adding some code to make it concrete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just create a Node if it is abstract.

You should be getting the input, and in that probably the type that wants to be created, and create the appropriate non abstract class for that one.

Alternatively you can create them as Category and if the user types an Id create a new Product and copy the data across from the first object to the second. But that doesn't makes much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like category should just be part of product. That is you have a category class, and a product class which has two properties: category class and id. That way, you can create a category out of any point on your graph, and then if it is a product, pass it to a second constructor to give it an id.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be an abstract method validate that each node type can implement independently.

Node suggests that this is a graph of states that you're navigating.  Perhaps you want a method to fire on entering or leaving that state.  Each type can put whatever they need into it.  Interfaces and strategy patterns will help here.

Keep the graph separate from what's done.